# UICollectionView - How to display Items with different heights in the same section?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I'm having trouble while displaying more items (with different values of height but with the same width) in the same section of a UICollectionView. The problem is the one shown below (the first image is what I'm trying to get, the second is what I actually have):

[UICollectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXmfj.png)

I've already implemented those 2 methods for the line spacing that I don't want:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

But I really don't know which other method I need to implement in order to achieve what I need. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that representation on the left of your screen with a basic collectionview layout. You need to create your own custom. You can look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186246/uicollectionview-layout-like-snapchat or there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364859/cells-order-in-uicollectionview/42365978#42365978

Answer (score 0):

you can use below way 
first implement **`UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`** protocol in your class then override 

    `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {}`
function in your class and return your size for cell for any cell you want

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I've already implemented that method and I already have the size that I want for the cells. ( I actually have the second situation shown in the image )
I'm just trying to figure out what can I do to have also the third cell below the second. If I won't get how to do it, I will just use 2 items of the same width and height.

Comment: Ok, then what is padding at top of green shape? Did you add it your self? I think it causes grey shape come down

Comment: No, it wasn't added by me! It was created in automatic.
Initially, I thought that items are allocated automatically wherever they have space to do it, but after this experience I think that it just happens when there's some space on the width for them! But not in the height. (as in the example)

Comment: Why you insist these views should be separated cells? Make all of them inside one cell and then make that cell full width. I think it is more simple

Comment: Yes, in fact I know that it's a solution as I've mentioned in the first comment ( " If I won't get how to do it, I will just use 2 items of the same width and height" = I'll join the grey and the green cell ) but I was curios to find a different approach!
PS: It works with different widths, but it's just more difficult when they also have different heights.

Comment: Anyway thanks for your help and the discussion Mohammad!