# iOS UICollectionView Horizontal Scrolling Rectangular Layout with different size of items?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

**iOS UICollectionView how to Create Horizontal Scrolling rectangular layout with different size of items inside.**

I want to create a Rectangular layout using UICollectionView like below. how can i achieve?

When i scroll **horizontally** using **CollectionView** 1,2,3,4,5,6 grid will scroll together to bring 7.

The Below are the dimensions of 320*480 iPhone Resolution. Updated Screen below.

[image]

First 6 items have below dimensions for iPhone 5s.

```
Item 1 Size is - (213*148)
Item 2 Size is - (106*75)
Item 3 Size is - (106*74)
Item 4 Size is - (106*88)
Item 5 Size is - (106*88)
Item 6 Size is - (106*88)
```

After item6 have same dimensions as collection View width and height like below.

```
Item 7 Size is - (320*237)
Item 8 Size is - (320*237)
Item 9 Size is - (320*237)
```

**How to create a simple custom Layout Using collection view, that has horizontal scrolling?**

Must appreciate for a quick solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this mean, when you scroll 1,2,3,4,5,6 grid will scroll together to bring 7 from right?

Comment: @chetananand : Yes

Comment: @chetananand: thanks for quick reply. I am using cocoacontrols.com/controls/squareflowlayout. Is it possible to i can update in same?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this library, so not sure if the library supports this. Maybe you can try to tweak it a be to achieve this.

Comment: @chetananand: I want to load the images as well. Any other ways we can achieve above design?

Comment: Why do you use fixed height and width? iOS devices has different width. I guess iphone below 6 has 320p width.

Comment: You should use UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout. https://www.raywenderlich.com/5436806-modern-collection-views-with-compositional-layouts

Comment: @mahan: The above will work for only ios 13 right? but my deployment target is ios9 only

Comment: Yes. iOS 13+ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Comment: @mahan: Any other way to achieve the above ui for to support to all the iOS models.

Comment: @chetananand: any other simpler way to achieve above UI. Please do suggest me.

Comment: I tried but I guss there is a problem with UICollectionView. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302585/vertical-uicollectionview-with-different-item-size?noredirect=1#comment110200799_62302585 . You can combine item 1 and 2 (5 and 6) by using  one item that contains two views. Read the update part.

Comment: @mahan : Yeah Thanks will check and update you

Comment: @mahan: I have tried above working Good. But only one issue is there, that is index 1 coming full horizontally. Can we split it to Two cells with equal width and height?

https://ibb.co/gwYwNWb

Comment: @mahan : Any Solution for below answer.

Comment: You should use a custom Layout (see there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364859/cells-order-in-uicollectionview/42365978#42365978 for an example). Only a custom one should be able to do what you want without using tricks (like separating a cell in two, etc.) Also, it's good to show in your schemas photos what are supposed to be the index cells, because it's harder to read them currently. I've worked on different one looking like yours, and depending on the client, the index would have different logic...

Comment: @Larme : Yes Correct but i need in swift. Please check my answer below, everything is good but only one issue is there, Index1 i have to split it to Index1 and Index2. Please correct me if any mistake is there in code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not about mistake, it's just it's not feasible with default layout. That's normal behavior. I strongly suggest you to learn how to read Objective-C code, not necessary master it and write it, but how to read it, since a lot of question have already Objective-C answers. Here is a sample on Swift: https://pastebin.com/0dAtqvV3 for quicker result, I made the small cells the same size. Once you understand that you have to calculate the frame for each cell, the calculation is up to you. render: https://imgur.com/QzTk1uw

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a StackView inside CollectionViewCell(of fixed dimension) to create a grid layout as shown in your post.

Below `GridStackView` creates a dynamic grid layout based on the number of views added using method `addCell(view: UIView)`.

Add this `GridStackView` as the only subview of your CollectionViewCell pinning all the edges to the sides so that it fills the CollectionViewCell completely.

while preparing your CollectionViewCell, add tile views to it using the method `addCell(view: UIView)`.

If only one view added, then it will show a single view occupying whole `GridStackView` and so as whole CollectionViewCell.
If there is more than one view added, it will automatically layout them in the inside the CollectionViewCell.

You can tweak the code below to get the desired layout calculating the row and column. Current implementation needed `rowSize` to be supplied while initializing which I used for one of my project, you need to modify it a bit to get your desired layout.

```swift
class GridStackView: UIStackView {
    private var cells: [UIView] = []
    private var currentRow: UIStackView?
    var rowSize: Int = 3
    var defaultSpacing: CGFloat = 5

    init(rowSize: Int) {
        self.rowSize = rowSize
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        axis = .vertical
        spacing = defaultSpacing
        distribution = .fillEqually
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        axis = .vertical
        spacing = defaultSpacing
        distribution = .fillEqually
    }

    private func preapreRow() -> UIStackView {
        let row = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [])
        row.spacing = defaultSpacing
        row.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        row.axis = .horizontal
        row.distribution = .fillEqually
        return row
    }

    func removeAllCell() {
        for item in arrangedSubviews {
            item.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        cells.removeAll()
        currentRow = nil
    }

    func addCell(view: UIView) {
        let firstCellInRow = cells.count % rowSize == 0
        if currentRow == nil || firstCellInRow {
            currentRow = preapreRow()
            addArrangedSubview(currentRow!)
        }
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cells.append(view)
        currentRow?.addArrangedSubview(view)
        setNeedsLayout()
    }
}
```

[image: Layout with current implementation]

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new cell that contains two views. Views have equal width.
- Contstruct your data accordingly

#### Data

```
struct ItemData {
    var color: [UIColor]
}

// NOTICE: 2nd item contains two colors and the rest one.
let data = [ItemData(color: [.red]), ItemData(color: [.blue, .purple]), ItemData(color: [.orange]),
            ItemData(color: [.cyan]), ItemData(color: [.green]), ItemData(color: [.magenta]),
            ItemData(color: [.systemPink]), ItemData(color: [.link]), ItemData(color: [.purple])]
```

---

#### Cell

```
class CollectionViewCellOne: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let identifier = "CollectionViewCellOne"

    var item: ItemData? {
        didSet {
            if let item = item {
                self.leadingLabel.backgroundColor = item.color.first!
                self.trailingLabel.backgroundColor = item.color.last!
            }
        }
    }

    let leadingLabel = UILabel()
    let trailingLabel = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.contentView.addSubview(leadingLabel)
        self.contentView.addSubview(trailingLabel)

        let width = self.frame.width / 2

        leadingLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        leadingLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        leadingLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        leadingLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        leadingLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        trailingLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        trailingLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        trailingLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        trailingLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        trailingLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

#### dequeueReusableCell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCellOne.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellOne
        cell.item = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    } else {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        if let color = data[indexPath.row].color.first {
            cell.backgroundColor = color
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried with [Mahan's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62302585/6285383) and i am getting the partially Correct output. But the issue is, index1 having full width of two items.

**How to split index 1 into index1 and Index2?**

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpCollectionView()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func setUpCollectionView() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
//        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
//        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let collectionView = CollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.bounces = false
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240).isActive = true
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

}
class CollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
        super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        self.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.identifier)
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
        self.isPagingEnabled = true

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

}
extension CollectionView: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = .blue
        cell.label.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

        let row = indexPath.row
        switch row {
        case 0:
            cell.backgroundColor = .red
        case 1:
            cell.backgroundColor = .blue
        case 2:
            cell.backgroundColor = .purple
        case 3:
            cell.backgroundColor = .orange
        case 4:
            cell.backgroundColor = .cyan
        case 5:
            cell.backgroundColor = .green
        case 6:
            cell.backgroundColor = .magenta
        case 7:
            cell.backgroundColor = .white
        case 8:
            cell.backgroundColor = .blue
        case 9:
            cell.backgroundColor = .green
        default:
            cell.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        }
        return cell
    }


}

extension  CollectionView: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let row = indexPath.row
        let width = collectionView.frame.width
        let other = width / 3

        let height = collectionView.frame.height
        let o_height =  height / 3
        switch row {
        case 0:
            return CGSize(width: other * 2, height: o_height * 2)
        case 1:
            return CGSize(width: other * 2, height: o_height)
        case 2:
            return CGSize(width: other, height: o_height)
        case 3:
            return CGSize(width: other, height: o_height)
        case 4:
            return CGSize(width: other, height: o_height)
        case 5, 6, 7:
            return CGSize(width: other, height: o_height)
        default:
            return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return .leastNormalMagnitude
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return .leastNormalMagnitude
    }
}



class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let identifier = "CollectionViewCell"

    let label = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.contentView.addSubview(label)
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

**How to devide index 1 into index1 and Index2 like below?**

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: How to devide cell 1 into Cell1 and Cell2?